# What are the stationarity conditions for an AR(4) process?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, autoregressive

The stationarity conditions for an AR(2) process are:

$$a_1 + a_2 < 1$$
$$a_2 - a_1 < 1$$
$$a_2 > -1$$

And the stationarity conditions for an AR(3) process are:

$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 < 1$$
$$a_2 - a_1 - a_3 < 1$$
$$a_1 a_3 + a_3^2 - a_2 < 1$$
$$a_1 - a_2 - 3 a_3 < 3 \quad  \textbf{ or } \quad 3 a_3 - a_1 - a_2 < 3$$

But what are the stationarity conditions for an AR(4) process? I cannot find them in the literature anywhere. I assume they must exist, because there exists an equation to find the roots of polynomials of order four, just like there exists formulas for orders three and two.

Comment: Welcome to the site! For clarity, it would be best to specify what the $a_x$ variables are. I assume they are the the AR-coefficients (that are usually denoted as $\phi$s in literature) as in: $y_t = \phi_0 + \phi_1 y_{t-1} + ... + \phi_p y_{t-p} + \varepsilon_t$, right?

Comment: @PaulG Yes, that is exactly what they are. Sorry for not specifying!

Comment: Would you mind also sharing how you got to the inequalities above or where you have them from?

Comment: @PaulG The textbook I am using is the 4th edition of Applied Econometric Time Series by Walter Enders, where these stationarity conditions can be found on pages 27 - 31.